Localization of modules and restriction of scalars
Suppose $\varphi : A \to B$ is a morphism of rings (commutative with unit).
Take $f \in A$ and write $g = \varphi(f)$. Write $A_f$ for the localization of $A$ at the multiplicative set $\{1,f,f^2,\dots\}$ and similarily for $B_g$. Let $M$ be an $B$-module; write $M_A$ for the restriction of scalars, seeing $M$ as an $A$-module via $\varphi$. Is it always true that
$$M_A \otimes_A A_f = (M \otimes_B B_g)_{A_f}$$
as $A_f$-modules? In other words, if I localize the module $M$ at $g$ and then view it as an $A_f$-module via $A_f \to B_g$ induced by $\varphi$, do I get the same thing as if I started by viewing $M$ as an $A$-module and then localized it at $f$?

It's easier to see what's going on if you write everything uniformly in terms of tensor products, including restriction of scalars. Restriction of scalars is given by the tensor product $(-) \otimes_B B$, viewing $B$ as a $(B, A)$-bimodule, so the LHS is
$$M \otimes_B B \otimes_A A_f$$
while the RHS is given by
$$M \otimes_B B_g$$
(viewing $B_g$ as a $(B, A_f)$-bimodule). So your question reduces to asking whether
$$B \otimes_A A_f \cong B_g$$
as $(B, A_f)$-bimodules. But this is clear: the LHS just inverts the action of $f$ on $B$ which exactly means inverting $g$.
